# HTTP client/ "file_get_contents()" makes Laravel application time out because of loading time

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently using Guzzle to fetch data from a resource, and this is inside 
a Laravel application. The function to fetch the API is located in the function of a controller. Whenever I load a page (in this case, the lead_tracker page declared in the controller below) requesting the API using Guzzle, the server just times out and gives me nothing. Why is this?

Here are the relevant files: the controller (web.php)

```
 <?php

  Route::get('/facebook_for_business', 'PageController@facebook_for_business_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/search_dominance', 'PageController@search_dominance_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/phone_management', 'PageController@phone_management_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/email_management', 'PageController@email_management_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/document_center', 'PageController@document_center_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/google_adwords', 'PageController@google_adwords_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/media_gallery', 'PageController@media_gallery_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/lead_tracker', 'PageController@lead_tracker_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/push_network', 'PageController@push_network_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/sub_account', 'PageController@sub_account_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'PageController@dashboard_page')->middleware('usersession');
  // Route::get('/dashboard', 'PageController@dashboard_page');
  Route::get('/calendar', 'PageController@calendar_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/register', 'PageController@register_page');//->middleware('usersession');
  // Route::get('/register', 'PageController@register_page');
  Route::get('/reviews', 'PageController@review_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/notes', 'PageController@notes_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/events', 'PageController@events_page')->middleware('usersession');

  Route::get('/privelege', 'PageController@privelege_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/login', 'PageController@login_page');
  // Route::get('/login', 'PageController@login_page')->middleware('usersession');
  Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
  Route::get('/logout', 'UsersController@logout');
  Route::get('/get_all_leads', 'LeadTrackerController@get_all');
  Route::get('/get_lead_details', 'LeadTrackerController@show');
  Route::get('/get_admin_id', 'UsersController@get_admin_id');
  Route::get('/get_sub_accounts/{id} ', 'UsersController@get_sub_accounts');


  Route::post('/authenticate_user', 'UsersController@authenticate');
  Route::post('/submit_register', 'UsersController@store');
  Route::post('/submit_add_lead', 'LeadTrackerController@store');
  Route::post('/submit_edit_lead', 'LeadTrackerController@update');
  Route::post('/submit_delete_lead/{id}', 'LeadTrackerController@destroy');

  Route::post('/submit_add_privelege', 'PrivelegesController@store');
```

the relevant controller (PageController.php)

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Auth;
    use File;

    class PageController extends Controller {
        private $data = array('title' => '', 'script' => '');

        public function index() {
            return redirect('/login'); 
        }

        public function dataTable($properties = array()){

            /*
                ID label
                columns
                API URL
                column names
            */

            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

            $idLabel = !isset($properties['id']) ? "a".md5(microtime()) : htmlspecialchars($properties['id']);
            $url = !isset($properties['url']) ? "" : htmlspecialchars($properties['url']);
            $html = "";

            $fetch = $client->request('GET', url($properties['url']), ['connect_timeout' => 3.14]);

            //$html = '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {  $("#'.$idLabel.'").DataTable( {   ';
            //$html .= "ajax: {url: '".$url."',dataSrc: 'data'},columns: [{ data: 'id' }]";
            //$html .= '} ); });</script>';


            $table = "<table id='".$idLabel."'>";
            $table .= "<thead class='thead-dark'><tr><th>id</th></tr></thead>";
            $table .= "</table>";


            $htmls = [
                'div' => $table, 
                'html' => $fetch->getBody()
            ];   

            return $htmls;
        }



        public function lead_tracker_page() {
            $data = $this->data;
            $data['title'] = 'ISR | Lead Tracker';


            $data['dataTable'] = $this->dataTable(['url' => '/get_all_leads']);



            $data['page_script'] = url('/') . '/js/pages/lead_tracker.js';
            return view('pages.lead_tracker_page')->with($data);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the connection time out to 3.14 seconds.

```
    $fetch = $client->request('GET', url($properties['url']), ['connect_timeout' => 3.14]);
```

This means that the guzzle client waits for 3.14 seconds and trying to connect to the requested URL. If it can't connect to the URL in 3.14 it throws timeout error.

So what you can do is :

1) delete the time out option and this way set it to default => zero (0)

(0) => means wait indefinitely (the default behavior)

or 2) raise the time out to be at least 10 seconds.

You can read about this option at [guzzle official website](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#connect-timeout)